# How to get sharepoint online (office 365) data in cloud/windows azure (provider) hosted app using Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

How to get sharepoint online (office 365) data in cloud/windows azure (provider) hosted app using Javascript?

I wish to retrieve sharepoint online data in html page (hosted in windows azure) using javascript and then need to play with AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

So you have a provider hosted app , registered in Sharepoint Online ?

I believe the need to take into account CORS issues.

Try this:

JavaScript

```
 executor.executeAsync(
{
    url:
        appweburl +
        "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/title?@target='" +
        hostweburl + "'",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
}
```

);

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx